# i3 screen black after opening lid on laptop

Tags: debian, i3

If I have monitors connected to my laptop and I close the lid on my laptop and then re-open the lid, then all screens become black and I have to reboot the computer.

How can I fix this?

I am using the i3 window manager with Debian 9. (I have 2 monitors connected to my laptop)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `gnome-terminal` will open a new terminal window. From there, do `startx` to restart your GUI.